# Align equations within a list

Tags: align, lists, itemize

I was wondering if there is a good solution to align math. equations separated by text items within a list. Below is my trial.

Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Text1:
    \begin{align*}
        C &= \begin{Bmatrix} \langle a_0,x \rangle\\ \vdots\\ \langle a_p,x\rangle \end{Bmatrix}_{\big| x \in \mathcal{H}}, & D &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}. \\ \\
        \shortintertext{\item Text2: \bigskip}
        C &= \begin{Bmatrix} \langle a_0,x\rangle\\\langle c_1,x\rangle\\ \vdots\\ \langle c_{r},x\rangle \end{Bmatrix}_{\big| x \in \mathcal{H}}, & D &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\ \\
        \shortintertext{\item Text3:  \bigskip}
        C &= \begin{Bmatrix} \langle a_0,x\rangle\\\langle b_1,x\rangle\\ \vdots\\ \langle b_{p},x\rangle \end{Bmatrix}_{\big| x \in \mathcal{H}}, & D &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot
    \end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only will remove superfluous line terminations (`\\`) and instead of `\shortintertext` use `\intertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Text 1:
    \begin{align*}
        C   & = \begin{Bmatrix} 
                \langle a_0,x \rangle\\ 
                \vdots\\ 
                \langle a_p,x\rangle 
                \end{Bmatrix}_{\big| x \in \mathcal{H}}, 
                & 
                D   & = \begin{pmatrix}
                        1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1
                        \end{pmatrix}.    
\intertext{\item Text 2:}
        C   & = \begin{Bmatrix} 
                \langle a_0,x\rangle\\
                \langle c_1,x\rangle\\ 
                \vdots\\ 
                \langle c_{r},x\rangle 
                \end{Bmatrix}_{\big| x \in \mathcal{H}}, 
                & 
                D   & = \begin{pmatrix} 
                        1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 
                        \end{pmatrix}
\intertext{\item \lipsum[66]}
        C   &= \begin{Bmatrix} 
                \langle a_0,x\rangle\\
                \langle b_1,x\rangle\\ 
                \vdots\\ \langle b_{p},x\rangle 
                \end{Bmatrix}_{\big| x \in \mathcal{H}}, 
                & 
                D   & = \begin{pmatrix} 
                        1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 
                        \end{pmatrix} \cdot
    \end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Zarko.